Empty issuer DN not allowed in X509Certificates
I am trying to implement Spring Security against Keycloak which is deployed on a local K3D cluster, configuration for which is given below:
application.yml:
spring:
  application:
    name: backend

  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: https://auth.photoatom.local/realms/PhotoAtom

SecurityConfiguration.java:
package com.photoatom.backend.Configuration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationConverter;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

  @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}")
  String issuerUri;

  interface AuthoritiesConverter extends Converter<Map<String, Object>, Collection<GrantedAuthority>> {
  }

  @Bean
  AuthoritiesConverter realmRolesAuthoritiesConverter() {
    return claims -> {
      final var realmAccess = Optional.ofNullable((Map<String, Object>) claims.get("realm_access"));
      final var roles = realmAccess.flatMap(map -> Optional.ofNullable((List<String>) map.get("roles")));
      return roles.map(List::stream).orElse(Stream.empty()).map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
          .map(GrantedAuthority.class::cast).toList();
    };
  }

  @Bean
  JwtAuthenticationConverter authenticationConverter(
      Converter<Map<String, Object>, Collection<GrantedAuthority>> authoritiesConverter) {

    var authenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();

    authenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(jwt -> {
      return authoritiesConverter.convert(jwt.getClaims());
    });

    return authenticationConverter;
  }

  @Bean
  JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {

    SSLContext sslSocket = createSslSocketFactory("certificates/keycloak/truststore.jks", "changeit",
        "certificates/keycloak/keystore.p12", "changeit");

    RestTemplate restOperations = new RestTemplate(new CustomRequestFactory(sslSocket));

    return NimbusJwtDecoder.withIssuerLocation(issuerUri)
        .restOperations(restOperations).build();
  }

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain resourceServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http,
      Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> authenticationConverter) throws Exception {

    http.oauth2ResourceServer(resourceServer -> {
      resourceServer.jwt(jwtDecoder -> {
        jwtDecoder.jwtAuthenticationConverter(authenticationConverter);
      });
    });

    http.sessionManagement(sessions -> {
      sessions.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }).csrf(csrf -> {
      csrf.disable();
    });

    http.authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> {
      requests.requestMatchers("/dummy").authenticated();
      requests.anyRequest().denyAll();
    });

    return http.build();
  }

  /**
   * Generate SSL Socket Factory for the provided certificates path and passwords.
   *
   * @param caCertPath       CA Certificate Path
   * @param caCertPassword   CA Certificate Password
   * @param userCertPath     User Certificate Path
   * @param userCertPassword User Certificate Password
   * @return SSLSocketFactory
   * @throws IOException
   * @throws GeneralSecurityException
   */
  private SSLContext createSslSocketFactory(
      String caCertPath, String caCertPassword, String userCertPath, String userCertPassword)
      throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {

    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
    keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(userCertPath), userCertPassword.toCharArray());

    KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
    trustStore.load(new FileInputStream(caCertPath), caCertPassword.toCharArray());

    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
    trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);

    KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("PKIX");
    keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, userCertPassword.toCharArray());

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);

    return sslContext;
  }

}

CustomRequestFactory.java:
package com.photoatom.backend.Configuration;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;

import org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory;

public class CustomRequestFactory extends SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory {

  private final SSLContext sslContext;

  public CustomRequestFactory(SSLContext sslContext) {
    this.sslContext = sslContext;
  }

  @Override
  protected void prepareConnection(java.net.HttpURLConnection connection, String httpMethod) throws IOException {
    if (connection instanceof javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection) {
      ((javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection) connection).setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
    }
    super.prepareConnection(connection, httpMethod);
  }
}

So what I am trying is that, loading up my self signed certificates for my Keycloak cluster to ensure I am using SSL connection when running authentication in my backend. But I am facing error which looks like this:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve the Configuration with the provided Issuer of "https://auth.photoatom.local/realms/PhotoAtom"
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.getConfiguration(JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.java:178) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.3.4.jar:6.3.4]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.getConfigurationForIssuerLocation(JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.java:90) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.3.4.jar:6.3.4]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.lambda$withIssuerLocation$2(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:226) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.3.4.jar:6.3.4]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder$JwkSetUriJwtDecoderBuilder.processor(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:389) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.3.4.jar:6.3.4]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder$JwkSetUriJwtDecoderBuilder.build(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:405) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.3.4.jar:6.3.4]
        at com.photoatom.backend.Configuration.SecurityConfiguration.jwtDecoder(SecurityConfiguration.java:79) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.photoatom.backend.Configuration.SecurityConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$jwtDecoder$2(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.photoatom.backend.Configuration.SecurityConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$FastClass$$1.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258) ~[spring-core-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:348) ~[spring-context-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
        at com.photoatom.backend.Configuration.SecurityConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0.jwtDecoder(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:146) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
        ... 74 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://auth.photoatom.local/realms/PhotoAtom/.well-known/openid-configuration": Failed to parse server certificates
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.createResourceAccessException(RestTemplate.java:915) ~[spring-web-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:895) ~[spring-web-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:740) ~[spring-web-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.getConfiguration(JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.java:167) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.3.4.jar:6.3.4]
        ... 87 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Failed to parse server certificates
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:130) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:378) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1282) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1195) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1138) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:393) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:476) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:447) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:201) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1506) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1421) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:586) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:187) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:141) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleClientHttpRequest.java:79) ~[spring-web-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
        at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractStreamingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractStreamingClientHttpRequest.java:70) ~[spring-web-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
        at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66) ~[spring-web-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:889) ~[spring-web-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
        ... 89 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: Empty issuer DN not allowed in X509Certificates
        at java.base/sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.parse(X509CertInfo.java:367) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.<init>(X509CertInfo.java:137) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.parse(X509CertImpl.java:1456) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.<init>(X509CertImpl.java:143) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.X509Factory.cachedGetX509Cert(X509Factory.java:113) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(X509Factory.java:97) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:355) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1278) ~[na:na]
        ... 107 common frames omitted

I am not exactly sure what I am doing wrong. I did notice the Issuer DN Missing error and after some googling, I found that, according to this issue on cert-manager (I am generating self signed certificates using cert-manager) and seems like adding commonName should help but it did not. I am also attaching certs I have generated locally for this for decoding:
tls.crt:
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

ca.crt:
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIBazCCARKgAwIBAgIQPgIxsF4n5MlqzY/IoTe3YTAKBggqhkjOPQQDAjAWMRQw
EgYDVQQDEwtrZXljbG9hay1jYTAeFw0yNDExMjcxMDE2MjBaFw0zMjExMjcxMDE2
MjBaMBYxFDASBgNVBAMTC2tleWNsb2FrLWNhMFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0D
AQcDQgAEJrTYx58qpmeRTpwgAcSWyMsZHshECyaLuyZzXWbHNYwWLepST9e7CxYQ
giuytx9cgOSDzZuA/yVJRKSWeSoyWaNCMEAwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgKkMA8GA1Ud
EwEB/wQFMAMBAf8wHQYDVR0OBBYEFDmmzF/TIlHr9rKBEOly+TSTzekuMAoGCCqG
SM49BAMCA0cAMEQCIBzTHUr8sUNi0/6x4IJl2k/fjYvr/jxAXfNZ4L8qPbl4AiAS
q9JGd8W3B5pl4BGd0YGY7V/XLDc72bEDhpjBtwhr3w==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Also to mention, I converted these certs to truststore and keystore files using the following commands:
openssl pkcs12 -export -in certificates/keycloak/tls.crt -inkey certificates/keycloak/tls.key -out certificates/keycloak/keystore.p12 -CAfile certificates/keycloak/ca.crt -caname keycloak-ca -name "keycloak"

keytool -importcert -keystore certificates/cache/truststore.jks -storepass changeit -file certificates/cache/ca.crt

Any help with this would be hugely appreciated, thanks so much in advance!

I suggest you don't post private keys on the public internet. "Security of public-key cryptography depends on keeping the private key secret".

Don't do it even if you are absolutely certain the private key is just self-signed/temporary/transient/non-production/whatever. Don't do it anywhere, whatever the justification - and certainly not here. If you have to show us something, show us the steps you took to generate the key - but not the key itself.

Removed it, they were ephemeral anyways
